# Error : remove the disk and press any key to restart

Tags: boot, usb-drive

I have problem with my USB memory ! 
So I am trying to make this USB memory bootable. Using unebooting, I uploaded a linux and set the booting to read from USB. but the laptop keeps giving this error :  remove the disk and press any key to restart.

Do I need to change some sector in USB ? what should I do, and how can I do it under a windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to work around the problem is to use a different program to create the bootable USB stick. It's recommended to use http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Comment: I also have tried tuxbood but didn't get the answer. I will try this universal usb installer, and write you back soon